# Hypothesis tests via permutation importance on validation data

Tags: modeling, feature-selection, permutation-test

A model agnostic way to measure variable importance of a variable $x$ in a statistical model (originately proposed by Breiman) is as follows:

1. Select a scoring function $\mu$ to measure model performance, e.g. MSE.
2. Calculate performance $\hat\mu$ of the model on a **truely independent** data set.
3. Shuffle column $x$ in that data set and calculate performance $\hat\mu_x$ on this shuffled data using the same model as above.
4. The drop in performance $\Delta = \hat\mu_x-\hat\mu$ quantifies the importance of $x$.

Steps 3 and 4 can be repeated to get multiple importances $\Delta_j$ for $x$.

Now my question: can we approximately reject the null of no importance based on a Wald test on $\Delta_j$? I.e. if a 95%-z ci derived from the sequence $\Delta_j$ does not contain 0, may we claim with about 95% certainty that $x$ has an effect on the model response?

Intuitively, I'd say yes. What do you think? Is there a good reference?